# Default folders for new users in G Suite

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business

I am fairly new to administering the G Suite of an organization. What I am trying to achieve is add specific folders to the Google Drive of all new users of a group - i.e. that these folders appear under `My Drive` for them, not just under `Shared with me` (see screenshot below).

I know I can share files/folder with all users in a specific group, and that they will be able to add these folders to their `My Drive` manually (e.g. after being provided with a link). However, I would like to save them from requiring this step by directly adding the files when creating the user account/adding it to a group.

In a similar vein, I would like to achieve the same for calendars - currently, I can share calendars with all users in a group, and they can manually add them to their list of calendars, but initially their calendar will be blank. I would like these shared calendars to be added right away.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest looking at the new Team Drives.  You probably need to turn them on first.  See this [Help Article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337635)

Comment: @Karl_S Thanks! But if I understand it correctly, the Team Drives are more limited in their functions (ordinary users can only move files, not folders; no specification of sharing for specific files; no sync; etc.) - so I fear I will need to stick to 'ordinary' folders/drives.

Comment: If you wish to use the classic folders, give them a link to the folder you wish them to access, adding ?usp=sharing to the end of the link.  It will look something like `https://drive.google.com/a/mydomain.com/folderview?id=0B7FYzrvwemtv0EyM2VBVDA&usp=sharing` .  When they open the link, in the top right should be a button to Add to Drive.  They then click that and the drive will show in their My Drive.  Note that I put this link on an intranet page for all new users to visit. That page has instructions for this and other items unique to the organization.

Comment: @Karl_S your replies seem to be as close as it gets to a solution. If you want to turn the comments into an answer, I could accept it (I guess both suggestions could be included).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, to provide an accepted answer:
If you wish to use the classic folders, give them a link to the folder you wish them to access, adding `?usp=sharing` to the end of the link. It will look something like `https://drive.google.com/a/mydomain.com/folderview?id=0B7FYz‌​rvwemtv0EyM2VBVDA&us‌​p=sharing`. When they open the link, in the top right should be a button to "Add to Drive". They then click that and the drive will show in their *My Drive*. Note that I put this link on an intranet page for all new users to visit. That page has instructions for this and other items unique to the organization.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to present a new user with company files, instead of trying to wrestle with Drive, create a company intranet on Google Sites to make all of your materials available.